# My Tortoise & Hare Java Project Won't Work

Tags: java, applet

I have to do this thing for my Java class where I make an applet displaying a tortoise & hare race.  Here is the assignment:

This project involves writing an applet to simulate a tortoise and hare race. The
contenders will each race along a horizontal course that contains a lane for each
of them. The course should have at least 50 squares or positions…you may add
more if you wish. The race begins with each contender at position 1 of their
respective lanes. The contender that first reaches or passes the last square of
the course is the winner of the race.
The following table indicates the types of moves that each contender can make.

```
Contender Type of Move Percentage of Time Result of Move
Tortoise Fast plod 50% 3 squares to right
Slow plod 30% 1 square to right
Slip 20% 6 squares to left
Hare Big hop 20% 9 squares to right
Small hop 30% 1 square to right
Big slip 10% 12 squares to left
Small slip 20% 2 squares to left
Fall asleep 20%
```

Each contender starts at position 1. When a contender slips, they can’t slip any
further left than position 1. You will use a random number generator to simulate
the percentages of each type of move indicated in the table.
Generate a random integer, n, in the range 1 ≤ n ≤ 10. For the tortoise, perform a
fast plod if the number is 1-5, a slow plod if the number is 6-8, and a slip if the
number is 9-10. For the hare, perform a big hop if the number is 1-2, a small hop
if the number is 3-5, a big slip if the number is 6, a small slip if the number is 7-8,
and fall asleep if the number is 9-10.
You must keep track of each contender’s position and display each contender’s
position using a graphics image. Graphics images for the tortoise and hare can
be found in the course downloads folder. You may have to adjust the length of
the course and the size of the applet window to get just the right look.
Hint: Get the overall logic for the program working before you deal with the
graphics. You might find it helpful (but it is not absolutely necessary) to structure
the overall control flow based on a simulation clock. Each time the clock “ticks”
the contenders move.

My program doesn't give an error message, but when I try to run it, I get a blank image of two rectangles with a bunch of divisions, it says "Race" and "Turn Null." I have tried the best I could to find what's wrong, but I think it could use a different pair of eyes. Please help if possible!

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class TortoiseAndHareProject extends Applet {
    Image tortoise, hare;  //creates two images, tortoise and hare
    int tortX = 250, hareX = 250;  //sets them both to start at pixel 250
    final int tortY = 100, hareY = 300, WIDTH = 15, HEIGHT = 50;  //sets finals tortY, hareY, WIDTH, and HEIGHT = variables to use in the race
                                                                            //WIDTH will serve as a counter for distance
    int turn;
    String turnNum;
    int move;
    String tMove, hMove;

    public void init() {
        tortoise = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "tortoise.gif");
        hare = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "hare.gif");
        move = 0;
        turn = 0;
    }

    public void control() throws InterruptedException {    
        while ((tortX < 985) || (hareX < 985)) {  //while neither has won the race yet (985 = finish)    
            move = (int) (10 * Math.random());    
            switch (move) {    
            case 1:      
            case 2:
                tortX += (3 * WIDTH);    
                hareX += (9 * WIDTH);    
                tMove = "Fast Plod";    
                hMove = "Big Hop";    
                break;    
            case 3:      
            case 4:    
            case 5:
                tortX += (3 * WIDTH);    
                hareX += WIDTH;    
                tMove = "Fast Plod";    
                hMove = "Small Hop";    
                break;    
            case 6:
                tortX += WIDTH;                     
                if (hareX == 250) {  //nothing happens, the hare just doesn't move    
                } else if (hareX <= (250 + (11 * WIDTH)))  //if hare is less than 12 squares ahead of 250    
                    hareX = 250;  //the hare just goes back to 250    
                else    
                    hareX -= (12 * WIDTH);  //the hare just moves back 12 * WIDTH    
                tMove = "Slow Plod";    
                hMove = "Big Slip";    
                break;    
            case 7:    
            case 8:
                tortX += (1 * WIDTH);    
                if (hareX == 250) {  //nothing happens, the hare just doesn't move    
                } else if (hareX <= (250 + (WIDTH)))  //if hare is less than 2 squares ahead of 250    
                    hareX = 250;  //the hare just goes back to 250    
                else    
                    hareX -= (2 * WIDTH);  //the hare just moves back 2 * WIDTH    
                tMove = "Slow Plod";    
                hMove = "Small Slip";    
                break;    
            case 9:    
            case 10:
                if (tortX == 250) {  //nothing happens    
                } else if (tortX <= (250 + (5 * WIDTH)))  //if the tortoise is less than 6 squares ahead of 250    
                    tortX = 250;  //the tortoise just goes back to 250    
                else    
                    tortX -= (6 * WIDTH);    
                tMove = "Slip";    
                hMove = "Fall Asleep.";    
                break;
            }    
            turn++;    
            turnNum = (turn + "");   
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(30);    
        }
        tortX = 985;    
        hareX = 985;    
        repaint();    
    }

    public void paint(Graphics screen) {    
        drawRace(screen);    
        if (tortX >= 985) {
                screen.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 48));    
            screen.drawString("Tortoise Wins", 650, 240);    
            clearCurrent(screen);    
            fillNext(screen);    
        } else if (hareX >= 985) {  //if hareX has gotten greater than 985    
            screen.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 48));    
            screen.drawString("Hare Wins", 650, 240);    
            clearCurrent(screen);    
            fillNext(screen);    
        } else {    
            screen.drawString(("Turn " + turnNum), 621, 55);    
            screen.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));    
            if (tMove != null) {    
                screen.drawString(tMove, 59, 65);    
            }    
            if (hMove != null) {    
                screen.drawString(hMove, 66, 255);    
            }    
            clearCurrent(screen);
            fillNext(screen);
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void clearCurrent(Graphics s) {
        s.clearRect(tortX + 1, tortY + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1);      
        s.clearRect(hareX + 1, hareY + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1);
                        //in order to get a new screen
    }

    public void fillNext(Graphics s) {
        s.fillRect(tortX + 1, tortY + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1);
        s.fillRect(hareX + 1, hareY + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1);
            //in order to fill the screen with the tortoise & hare
    }

    public void drawRace(Graphics s) {
        s.drawRect(250, 100, 750, 50);  //draws a rectangle for the race
        s.drawRect(250, 300, 750, 50);  //draws another rectangle for the race
        int lineX = 265, lineYi = 100, lineYf = 150;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 98; i++) {  //for the duration of the race
            if (lineX == 1000) {
                lineX = 265;
                lineYi = 300;
                lineYf = 350;    
            }
            s.drawLine(lineX, lineYi, lineX, lineYf);
            lineX += 15;
        }
        s.fillRect(tortX + 1, tortY + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1);
        s.fillRect(hareX + 1, hareY + 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1);
        s.drawImage(tortoise, 59, 80, this);
        s.drawImage(hare, 66, 271, this);
        s.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24));
        s.drawString("Race", 250, 55);
    }

    public void stop() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A good question might read, "This method doesn't work. I expected it to do Foo, but it actually does Bar." This question is more like, "My program doesn't work. Here is the entire assignment, and the output of my entire program."

Comment: Please get rid of all the blank lines so people can actually see your code. Nobody cares how quickly you need assistance.

Comment: I fixed it for you. Please have a good look and learn. I removed 99% of your comments, as they were asinine. Comments that merely repeat the code are pointless, and worse: they clutter up the joint. Comments should say what you are trying to accomplish, not what you're doing to try to accomplish it. And all those blank lines are equally just a waste of space, literally. Don't write code like this.